# How to know if a semaphore is going to block my process

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I'm making in java a work for my college , and i need to know if there are some way for knowing if a semaphore will block a process with an aquire .

Comment: there are many different types of locks in java.  what one are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you are using `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`:

> boolean   tryAcquire()
>
> Acquires a permit from this semaphore, only if
>   one is available at the time of invocation.

```
boolean acquired = semaphore.tryAcquire();
if (acquired) {
    System.out.println("Got it!");
    semaphore.release();
} else {
    System.out.println("Returned immediately, would have blocked");
}
```