# Print before invoking wait() in a semaphore

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to implement a bounded buffer in Java to learn more about concurrency. Several threads will access this buffer for using the add() and remove() methods. I'm using three semaphores to allow this to happen (one for num of items available, num of spaces available and a binary semaphore for the critical section). When the buffer is full/empty I'd like to print "buffer full" or "buffer empty" respectively.

I've put the print statement for full/empty before I invoke wait() in the semaphore. This however, seems to be printing full/empty far more than it should and at the wrong time. I assume it's context switching at the wrong time. Should I change where I put the print statement?

My `Semaphore` class that is able to print full/empty with the prtstmt parameter

```
public class Semaphore {

  private String prtstmt;
  private int count;

  public semaphore(String prtstmt, int count) {
    this.count = count;
    this.prtstmt = prtstmt;
  }

  public synchronized void V(){
    count = count + 1;
    notify();
  }

  public synchronized void P(){
    count = count - 1;
    if (count < 0) {
      System.out.println(prtstmt);
      wait();
    }
  }

}
```

The bounded buffer

```
public class BoundedBufferUsingSemaphore {

private static final int SIZE = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Semaphore full = new Semaphore(0, "Buffer full!");
    Semaphore empty = new Semaphore(SIZE, "Buffer Empty!");
    Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1, null);
    Vector<Integer> sQueue = new Vector<Integer>();

    Thread producerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                empty.p();
                mutex.p();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is trying to insert item " + i);
                sQueue.add(i);
                mutex.v();
                full.v();
            }
        }
    });

    Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                full.p();
                mutex.p();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " consuming item " + sQueue.remove(0));
                mutex.v();
                empty.v();
            }
        }
    });

    producerThread.setName("Producer");
    consumerThread.setName("Consumer");

    consumerThread.start();
    producerThread.start();

}
}
```

A Sample output is as follows

```
Consumer consuming item 5
Buffer empty!
Producer is trying to insert item 6
Producer is trying to insert item 7
Consumer consuming item 6
Producer is trying to insert item 7
Consumer consuming item 6
Buffer empty!
Consumer consuming item 5
Buffer empty!
Producer is trying to insert item 6
Producer is trying to insert item 7
Consumer consuming item 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The Native Semaphore does something like this!

```
boolean acquired = semaphore.tryAcquire();
if (acquired) {
    System.out.println("Got it!");
    semaphore.release();
} else {
    System.out.println("Returned immediately, would have blocked");
}
```

Sourced: [How to know if a semaphore is going to block my process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160851/how-to-know-if-a-semaphore-is-going-to-block-my-process)